# Azure DevOps team and work item structure for larger projects which affects multiple systems

Tags: azure-devops, project, sprint

I am currently trying configure a good Azure DevOps setup to work on projects which affecting multiple systems (teams).
My goal is to achieve a "project" view and a "system" view.
The project leader needs the project view and the developers need the system view.

Right now we are working for normal requirements and change requests etc. with teams for the different systems.
For example we have the systems database, web api and frontend.
Every system has its own team, so there are three teams with their own backlogs.
Those teams are working with the same two week sprints to allow a better planning of developers which are part of multiple teams.
For example a developer could be part of database and web api team.
Every team has its own area paths, e.g. if there are two frontend applications each application could have its own area path.
This setup works pretty fine for the daily business.

But now there is another complexity level for projects across multiple teams.
Lets say we have a project named "Large Project" to create a completly new application with a database, web api and frontend.
Then we are current creating a new team "Large Project" in Azure DevOps.
The project leader is working on that team to have a full overview about the project.
We create epics and features in this project team, the requirements below the features are then assigned to the system teams and are planned into sprints of those teams.
This leads to information loss inside the system teams, because we do not see the parents of those requirements in the backlog of those teams.
Therefore it is for example hard to sum up the whole estimation for one system.

I searched a lot in the web but I did not came across a better solution than that.
Does anyone have a better solution / setup to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

On the Backlog page for Requirements of a team, you can expend the parent work items via the way like as below:
Click "**More actions**" > "**View options**" > turn on "**Parents**" option.

With this setting, you can see all the parents (**Epics** and **Features**) of the Requirements are showing on the page. For other Backlog pages and other teams, you can use the same way to turn on "**Parents**" option.

[image]